# C# - Generic type function is trying to assign result to System.Func(specified type) when a function with parameters is passed in

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics

I'm using a class with a method that looks like the following:

```
public static T Get<T>(string key, Func<T> method)
    {
        //do stuff
        var obj = method.Invoke();
        return (T)obj
    }
```

It works great if it I call it like this:

```
var x = Get<string>("mykey", test);
```

Where test is a function that has no parameters and returns a string. However, things break as soon as test has parameters. If I try:

```
var x = Get<string>("mykey", test(myparam));
```

I get the error "Argument type "String" is not assignable to parameter type "System.Func< string >".

I know the addition of (myparam) is the problem, but I'm not sure how it should be fixed. Is the issue with how the library's function is written or with how I'm trying to pass in the parameter?

Comment: `Func<T>` models a function that takes no parameter. You need `Func<T1,T2>` for this and an invoke that passes the parameter in.

Comment: Also `.Invoke()` is redundant.  You can call functions parameters as if they were just plain functions: `var obj = method()`.

Comment: You need to pass a function that has no parameters, and returns a string. `test(myparam)` causes the function `test` to be invoked with parameter `myparam` before `get` is called. This evaluates to a string. As in the answers below, `() => test(myparam)` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call it like in the following sample code:

`Get("mykey", () => test(myparam))`

```
    public static T Get<T>(string key, Func<T> method)
    {
        //do stuff
        var obj = method.Invoke();
        return (T)obj;
    }
    void Xyz()
    {
        int myparam = 0;
        var x = Get("mykey", () => test(myparam)); // <string> is not needed
    }
    double test(int i)
    {
        return 0.0;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var x = Get<string>("mykey", () => test(myparam));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to [curry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) the parameter by passing a lambda expression that takes no parameters and calls your function with a parameter from elsewhere:

```
var x = Get<string>("mykey", () => test(myparam));
```

Comment: Technically this is not currying.  Currying is a transformation that takes a two-parameter function to two nested one-parameter functions (or generalize for `n` parameters).

Comment: @luqui: I don't see why not.  I'm transforming from a 1-param to a 0-param

Comment: Seems to me you are transforming a value (of type String) to a 0-param function (of type Func<String>).

Comment: @Luqui: No; I'm transforming `test`.

Comment: Currying is this:  `(x,y) => f(x,y)`  transformed to `x => (y => f(x,y))`.  See the difference?  All arguments are preserved, we are just changing how they are passed.  Here you are closing over an argument in the environment -- `test` used to take `myparam` and tranformed function takes *nothing*.

Comment: @luqui: No, I don't see the difference.  You're going from 2 to 1; I'm going from 1 to 0.

Comment: You're indeed going from 1 to 0, but I'm not going from 2 to 1.  I'm going from 2 to *two* 1s.  Currying preserves the total number of arguments, it just rearranges how they are passed.

Answer (score 0):

It's how you're passing the parameter.  `test(myparam)` has type `String`, and you need to pass *a function* which returns a `String`.  You can make one with very little effort using a lambda expression:

```
var x = Get<string>("mykey", () => test(myparam));
```

The lambda expression `() => foo` creates a function which, when called, executes and returns `foo`.

Answer (score -1):

You need to change your Func definition to define the input params thus:

```
Func<T,T1,T2,T3> method
```

Comment: Nope.  He could define eg. `Get<T,T1>(string key, Func<T1, T> method, T1 arg)`, and pass `arg` to `method`, but the same thing can be accomplished with a closure without changing the signature, as seen in the other answers.